# Recording UI performance of Applet on a webpage

Tags: swing, applet, html, web-hosting

I have created an applet which is a java swing based messenger which runs fine on browsers. Now i have to host this applet on a webpage and allow users to test my applet. I need to record time they take for each task using the messenger and and the errors they commit. After the study is complete the user has to be displayed the time and the no of errors.

I am not able to figure out how to record times for each task that the user has to do in my messenger application. one way would be to record time on click of right buttons I can do it programmatically in Java Swing for correct click on buttons, but how do i send this info to HTML Page from an applet.

I don't have any clue how i would capture errors.

Suggestions needed

Comment: *"Suggestions needed"*  1) Ask a question. 2) Leave sigs. out of questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing exception and the [info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#info%28java.lang.String%29) you can use a [Logger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html).

From doc,

`A Logger object is used to log messages for a specific system or application component.`

So when you get any exception write it to the Logger file. It has all the set of required methods to log the information.

**Example:**
When you are entering a method use [Logger.entering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#entering%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to log the method entry. Similarly you have to write all the actions using respective methods provided by `Logger` class which may either be message or exceptions or errors which ever you want to show to the user through this log file.

**P.S:** We use it in our application and it is very handy.

Comment: but i am not expected to log exceptions. I am expected to log scenarios where user was supposed to click the next button but he dint (may because he dint understand the UI). Those are the errors I am talking about. Time to do a specific task on UI (like adding a friend in messenger) and the errors.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what **info** will do for you. When entering a class use entering method defined already in Logger. Try it out it helps.